# How to label specific points on x-axis in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

[image]

How do I get the x-axis to only show those two values when I plot?

Comment: You need to change the `'XTickLabel'` property: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92565-how-do-i-control-axis-tick-labels-limits-and-axes-tick-locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `XTick` and `XTickLabel`, e.g.:

```
x = -pi:pi/360:pi;
y = sin(x)
plot(x,y)
doc xtick
set(gca,'XTick',[-pi/2 pi/2],'XTickLabel',{'-\pi/2','\pi/2'})
```

which gives something like this:

[image]

See [Change Axis Tick Values and Labels](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html) in the documentation for more details.

Comment: What if I want to type complex math symbol using Latex, e.g., $\sqrt{2}-1$ in the 'XTickLabel', then is there a way to achieve that?